# Code style in ruby on rails: how to include a line break in a string expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, line-breaks

I have this kind of code:

```
<%= link_to very_long_and_boring_string_variable_name + another_very_long_and_boring_string_variable_name, some_path %>
```

I would like to re-style my code like so:

```
<%= link_to very_long_and_boring_string_variable_name
+ another_very_long_and_boring_string_variable_name, some_path %>
```

The second example however seems to give a compilation error.
The error I'm getting here is 'Unexpected symbol ...'
Can this be achieved and if so, how ?

PS: My variable names aren't actually that long but for the sake of this question, they are.

Comment: The second example should be legal. What error do you get?

Comment: alright you answered this question, what I did is that I had the `+` on the next line and that's illegal apparently whereas having it on the first line is OK. Can you add the answer and I'll mark it ? If not, we can just close this.

Comment: `<%=` and `%>` are not required to be on the same line. This shouldn't be an issue. Have you tried a more minimal example?

Comment: I think it might still be interesting for others to know that you can't have the line-break wherever you want to as it was a bit confusing to me at first, too.